# Unable to access local Git repo after quitting during a rebase

Tags: git, repository, git-rebase, git-stash

My virtual machine shutdown during a `git rebase` and now the project directory has no sight of the Git repository at all. When I do a `git status` I get the following:

```
vagrant@localhost /var/www/crmpicco $ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I tried re-initialising the repo, but that had no effect:

```
vagrant@localhost /var/www/crmpicco $ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /var/www/releases/20141013104615/.git/
vagrant@localhost /var/www/crmpicco $ git status
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Inside my .git directory I have the following:

```
vagrant@localhost /var/www/crmpicco/.git $ ls -all
total 92
drwxr-xr-x+   9 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jul  8 09:26 .
drwxr-xr-x+  18 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jul  7 18:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x+   2 vagrant vagrant    6 Oct 13  2014 branches
-rw-rw-r--+   1 vagrant vagrant  293 May  6 16:45 COMMIT_EDITMSG
-rw-rw-r--+   1 vagrant vagrant  637 Jul  8 09:26 config
-rw-r--r--+   1 vagrant vagrant   73 Oct 13  2014 description
-rw-rw-r--+   1 vagrant vagrant 4157 Jul  7 17:56 FETCH_HEAD
-rw-rw-r--+   1 vagrant vagrant    0 Jul  7 18:00 HEAD
drwxr-xr-x+   2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Oct 13  2014 hooks
-rw-rw-r--+   1 vagrant vagrant    0 Jul  7 18:00 index
drwxr-xr-x+   2 vagrant vagrant   20 Oct 13  2014 info
drwxr-xr-x+   3 vagrant vagrant   28 Oct 13  2014 logs
drwxr-xr-x+ 259 vagrant vagrant 8192 Apr 29 09:31 objects
-rw-rw-r--+   1 vagrant vagrant   41 Jul  7 17:56 ORIG_HEAD
-rw-r--r--+   1 vagrant vagrant 3442 Oct 13  2014 packed-refs
drwxrwxr-x+   2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Jul  7 18:00 rebase-apply
drwxr-xr-x+   5 vagrant vagrant   55 Jul  7 16:22 refs
```

I have a handful of files in the `git stash` that i'd like to keep.

How can I recover the repo and those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I had corrupted Git files (caused by my virtual machine going down during a `git rebase`) as the solution to this problem was to do delete my local files and do a fresh checkout of the code.

I tried rebuilding the Git index, however that had no effect.

If you don't have files that you need to commit then this would probably work for you and is likely to be a quicker route to get back up and running that any other suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the `HEAD` file, and see if it' a pointer to e.g. `ref: refs/heads/master` or a SHA hash.

If it's a pointer then look in `refs/heads/master` and see if that's got a hash. If it has, try running `git log` on the hash to see if you can recover things. If you can, `git reset --hard HASH` should do the right thing.

You can also run `git fsck` which will do consistency checking on the files and perhaps give you further indication as to what the problem is. You should also check that the `config` file looks sensible (read; isn't corrupted).